# Model design and LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, code-first

Im having a problem with the design of my Models. The application has Modules (I.e. University modules) which are taught by one or many Lecturers, Lecturers can also teach one or many Modules, therefore in terms of database design there is a Many-to-many relationship between Modules and Lecturers, hence in my database this relationship will be represented by an addition table that has Module_id and Lecturer_id as a composite key to achieve this I included a list of lecturers in the module class with the virtual modifier and visa versa, as seen below

```
public class Module
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Department department { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Lecturer> lecturers { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And the lecturer class:

```
public class Lecturer
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Module> modules { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

My first question is, is this the best way to implement this situation in the Models? It seems to work ok, however this means that Modules have Lecturers which teach Modules which then Taught by the Lecturers... and so on, and hence seems very inefficient and not optimal. It also means that I cannot simply return, for example a Module as a JSON object to the browser because of this loop.

Finally, if this is the correct implementation is there a way using LINQ to query for a Module and then return a limited Module that has Lecturers but then the Lectures are restricted and do not have modules associated with them? At the moment I am using the following statement?

```
Module module = dbContext.Modules.Where(r => r.id == id).Single();
```

Comment: If you want comments on the design of your program, you should go to Programmers.SE. If you want answers regarding the code itself, you should probably paste the code you're having specific trouble with.

Comment: I disagree with @GeorgeStocker -- this is a perfectly valid question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Randolpho It's a *design* question (he even says so in the title). As such, it's a programmers question.

Comment: I apologies for the confusion, I shouldn't have used 'design' implementation would have been better - my question pretty much comes down to best practice for the implementation of many-to-many relationships in code first approach with entity framework - because by current implementation has problems

Comment: You guys are philistines!  I was actually helping this person!  They should take the close option away.  Philistines, I swear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, when dealing with many-to-many relationships, I like to make the relationship table a concrete part of my model.  That is, I would have a `LecturerModule` table that both `Lecturer` and `Module` reference.  In a many-to-many relationship, the relationship is a thing.  This makes the most architectural sense for me and makes models so much easier to work with rather than trying to hide the relationship in some sort of complex looped tree.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was wondering with this approach, if a Module no longer has a list of Lecturers would you have to for example if a new module was added update the module and ModuleLecturer tables with separate LINQ statements and also when manipulating Module objects if you were concerned with what Lecturers this Module had would you have to query for them separately or is there a way you could access them as part of the Module class, sorry if im confusing you im having trouble putting my question into words myself

Comment: All I'm saying is that you cannot have, in a relational database, a many-to-many relationship between two tables without an intermediate table. I know that you know this. Making that relationship table a part of my model has given me the best results. In your case, a Module is not really contained by a Lecturer, neither is vice-versa.  Therefore, containership doesn't really reflect the model. It has always made the most sense to include the intermediate table as a separate entity that is owned by both sides. I've not used code first yet, so I could be misunderstanding what you are doing...

Comment: .. But the relationship is a thing, and making it into an entity in and of itself, has always been better for me.  Modules can exist without Lecturers and vice-versa.  A Module doesn't own a Lecturer or vice-versa, outside of the existence of a ModuleLecturer.  That entity establishes that relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, after the question was closed I went on to find this tutorial [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which has both mine and your approach, which has helped me to clarify what I need todo, thanks again

Comment: Not a problem.  I'll have to read it myself.  I swear, they are philistines, the lot!